# метод is not a function, когда массив объектов

Tags: javascript

```
class CityMap {
    constructor (city, latitude, longitude) {
        this.city = city;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
      TestMethod (){
          console.log("hello")
      }
}

let ObjArrayCityMap = [
        new CityMap( "Nashville, TN", 36.17, -86.78),
        new CityMap( "New York, NY", 40.71, -74.00),
        new CityMap( "Atlanta, GA", 33.75, -84.39),
        new CityMap( "Denver, CO", 39.74, -104.98),
        new CityMap( "Seattle, WA", 47.61, -122.33),
        new CityMap( "Los Angeles, CA", 34.05, -118.24),
        new CityMap( "Memphis, TN", 35.15, -90.05),
    ];
ObjArrayCityMap.TestMethod()
console.log(ObjArrayCityMap)
```

Метод "TestMethod" выдает ошибку при выводе, "ObjArrayCityMap.TestMethod is not a function", такая проблема, только при массиве объектов, не могу понять почему.

Comment: А на какой результат вы рассчитываете?)

Answer (score 5):

У *элементов* массива такой метод есть. У самого массива - нет.

```js
class CityMap {
  constructor(city, latitude, longitude) {
    this.city = city;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
  }
  TestMethod() {
    console.log("Hello,", this.city)
  }
}

let ObjArrayCityMap = [
  new CityMap("Nashville, TN", 36.17, -86.78),
  new CityMap("New York, NY", 40.71, -74.00),
  new CityMap("Atlanta, GA", 33.75, -84.39),
  new CityMap("Denver, CO", 39.74, -104.98),
  new CityMap("Seattle, WA", 47.61, -122.33),
  new CityMap("Los Angeles, CA", 34.05, -118.24),
  new CityMap("Memphis, TN", 35.15, -90.05),
];
ObjArrayCityMap.forEach(item => item.TestMethod());
```