# Вернуть значение из массива объектов. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Определите новый объект с именем «CityMap», который можно создать с помощью «new», используя его конструктор. Конструктор принимает один параметр в виде строки - это список городов и их широт и долгот: «Нэшвилл, Теннесси», 36,17, -86,78; "Нью-Йорк, Нью-Йорк", 40,71, -74,00; «Атланта, Джорджия», 33,75, -84,39; Объект «CityMap» должен иметь следующий метод: Возвращать название самого северного, самого восточного, самого южного или самого западного города из списка в соответствии с запросом вызывающей стороны.

```js
function CityMap(str) {

  function CityMapRecording(str) {
    [this.city, this.latitude, this.longitude] = str.split(" ,")
  }
  this.list = [];
  str.split(";").forEach(row => {
    this.list.push(new CityMapRecording(row));
  });
  CityMap.prototype.get = function(cityName) {
    return this.list[cityName];
  };
  this.getEasternmostCity = function() {
    return this.list.reduce(
      (EasternmostCity, currentMap) =>
      ({
        'longitude': Math.max(EasternmostCity.longitude, currentMap.longitude)
      })
    );
  }
}
var cityMap = new CityMap("Nashville, TN ,36.17 ,-86.78;New York, NY ,40.71 ,-74.00;Atlanta, GA ,33.75 ,-84.39;Denver, CO ,39.74 ,-104.98;Seattle, WA ,47.61 ,-122.33;Los Angeles, CA ,34.05 ,-118.24;Memphis, TN , 35.15 ,-90.05")
console.log(cityMap.list)
console.log(cityMap.getEasternmostCity())
```

Не могу никак понять, как мне вернуть конкретно название города(и его штат) из массива объектов. Получается только вернуть долготу самого восточного города, а вернуть его название никак не получается, банально, не знаю как, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073740

Answer (score 2):

Возвращайте из функции весь объект.

```js
function CityMap(str) {

  function CityMapRecording(str) {
    [this.city, this.latitude, this.longitude] = str.split(" ,");
  }
  this.list = [];
  str.split(";").forEach(row => {
    this.list.push(new CityMapRecording(row));
  });
  CityMap.prototype.get = function(cityName) {
    return this.list[cityName];
  };
  this.getEasternmostCity = function() {
    return this.list.reduce(
      (eastern, current) => {
        if (+eastern.longitude < +current.longitude)
          return current;
        else
          return eastern;
      }
    );
  }
}
var cityMap = new CityMap("Nashville, TN ,36.17 ,-86.78;New York, NY ,40.71 ,-74.00;Atlanta, GA ,33.75 ,-84.39;Denver, CO ,39.74 ,-104.98;Seattle, WA ,47.61 ,-122.33;Los Angeles, CA ,34.05 ,-118.24;Memphis, TN , 35.15 ,-90.05");
//console.log(cityMap.list);
console.log("Easternmost:", cityMap.getEasternmostCity().city);
```